jQuery not loaded for direct page hit, but is when navigating to the same page
I have a NextJS app that has a page which has a sub-component on it that utilizes the isPropagationStopped method from jQuery from within my index.js.
index.js is loaded from an external source, however it is definitely allowed through CSP.
On every other page on my site that I load, I can see that jQuery is loaded correctly, however for this particular page, I occasionally get an error:-
Uncaught TypeError: l.isPropagationStopped is not a function
    at ta (index.js:37:31808)

The error only occurs:-

in Production on our Vercel app
on a direct page load of the URL in the browser (not when navigating to it from a link).

We have attempted to load index.js using the afterInteractive strategy, and also defer=false, but neither have solved the problem.
And because I can't replicate this on local (running the same npm commands) I'm not sure what else I can do.
Does anyone know why this is happening or have any suggestions on what else we can check?
Thanks
